# adding tick marks in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js have a horizontal div that I would like to add tick marks too.  Using an example I was able to create tick marks on a vertical line but when I try to append it to `#bar` with 
`var svg = d3.select("#bar")` the tick marks disappear.  How should one append tick marks to a `div`?

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain([0, 1, 2])
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([250, 0]);

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(6, ));
```

```css
  #bar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 0 px solid black;
  background: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.8);
  color: #eee;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<div id = 'bar'></div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to draw an axis in an HTML div, is that correct? The axis generator creates `<g>`, `<path>` and `<line>` elements, and those will work inside an SVG, not inside an HTML div. Only the texts will show up (but not to the scale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GerardoFurtado is correct you can only add them to the svg. You can take what you had applied for the y-axis and modify it to the x-axis.

You can assign a class to the path and then style it using the svg [style attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes)

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain([0, 1, 2])
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([250, 0]);

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(6, ));
        
g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",250)")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(6, ));
```

```css
.bar path{
  fill: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.8);;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.bar .tick text{
  fill: darkgrey;
}

.bar .tick line{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```